# Hover is not working for two elements at a time

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want that whenever I hover on an image, it should show two icons - that is delete & camera icons. But currently I am able to see only one icon that is of delete.

For this I have used CSS as given below

```css
#cover-img:hover + #nav-upload-icon + #nav-remove-icon,
#nav-upload-icon:hover,
#nav-remove-icon:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
#nav-upload-icon,
#nav-remove-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.fa-camera:before {
  content: "\f030";
  margin-right: -12px;
  margin-top: -88px;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 10px; */
  /* left: 10px; */
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* opacity: 0; */
}
.fa-remove:before {
  content: "\f00d";
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -24px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FF0000;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1" class="profile-pic" id="cover-img" onerror="this.src='images/user-icon.png'" /> <i id="nav-upload-icon" class="fa fa-camera"></i><i id="nav-remove-icon" class="fa fa-remove"></i> 
<input id="ip" type='file' style="display:none;" />
<input id="ip1" type='file' accept="image/*;capture=camera" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: I would put both icons in a container (span, or div, depending what works best for you), then you can activate your hover event on container and not each icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one selector in your selector group. The below selector would select only the `i` tag with `id='nav-remove-icon'` when you `:hover` on the element with `id='cover-img'`.

```css
#cover-img:hover + #nav-upload-icon + #nav-remove-icon
```

It would not select both the icons. You would have to include the below selector also to get both icons to display.

```css
#cover-img:hover + #nav-upload-icon
```

Another thing that might be worth noting is that the two icons are positioned at an offset from the image and so the selectors -  `#nav-upload-icon:hover` and `#nav-remove-icon_hover` will never be triggered because those icons become visible only when image is hovered on. As soon as we move the mouse away from the image (to hover on the icons itself), they become invisible. So, while this solution would work for your case, it might also be worth having a look at [Jurion's suggestion in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618494/hover-is-not-working-for-two-elements-at-a-time/35618563#comment58919884_35618494).

**Demo:**

```css
#cover-img:hover + #nav-upload-icon + #nav-remove-icon,
#cover-img:hover + #nav-upload-icon,
#nav-upload-icon:hover,
#nav-remove-icon:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
#nav-upload-icon,
#nav-remove-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.fa-camera:before {
  content: "\f030";
  margin-right: -12px;
  margin-top: -88px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-remove:before {
  content: "\f00d";
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -24px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FF0000;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1" class="profile-pic" id="cover-img" onerror="this.src='images/user-icon.png'" /> <i id="nav-upload-icon" class="fa fa-camera"></i><i id="nav-remove-icon" class="fa fa-remove"></i>  
<input id="ip" type='file' style="display:none;" />
<input id="ip1" type='file' accept="image/*;capture=camera" style="display:none;"/>
```

Comment: @RajeshChoudhary: Yes pal, I saw that. The notification might have come because I edited the answer a bit :)